# "No module named 'dotenv'" in my Discord Bot

Tags: python, api, discord

I am new to coding Discord Bots and when I made a test where the Bot connects to the API, I get this error message in Visual Studio Code when I try to launch it.

`Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'dotenv'
File "C:\Users\Matteo\dipy\bot.py", line 5, in 
from dotenv import load_doten

My Code:

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('my token')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} hat sich mit Discord verbunden!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Did you install it with `pip` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `python-dotenv`:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: I tried it in a new virtual environment and it worked correctly. Did you correctly set python interpreter?